# mongoimport csv syntax error

Tags: mongodb, csv, syntax-error

I am trying to import a large csv file to mongodb but I am getting an error:

```
[thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:15
```

I downloaded the file from http://s3.amazonaws.com/open_data/opendata_projects000.gz

Extracted in linux and renamed as `opendata_projects.csv`

After running `mongod` and `mongo`, I tried importing the csv file to mongodb using the import command:

```
mongoimport -d donorschoose -c projects --type csv --file opendata_projects.csv -headerline
```

I am using mongodb v3.4 in a Windows 7 machine.  Is the data not a valid csv? Its quite large, is there a quick way to validate if its a valid csv file?

Per lascort's comment, the issue was because I was running the import command in mongo shell not in the command prompt.  Once I ran it in the command prompt, I am getting the error:

`Failed: fields cannot be identical: '' and ''`

Comment: its `--headerline`, not `-headerline`

Comment: @lascort either one gives me the same error

Comment: Are you by any chance running this in the mongo shell? `mongoimport` runs in command prompt, not mongo shell

Comment: @lascort Ohh.  Yes i was running it on mongo shell.  When i ran it in command prompt i got the error: Failed: fields cannot be identical: '' and ''.  Do you know why that is?

Comment: Well, you probably have columns with the same header

Comment: @lacsort The file actually does not have headers and multiple columns do have the same value.  Instead of using --headerline i used -f 1,2,3,4,..44.  Since there were 44 columns I placed each to have column numbers for now.  Is there a shortcut of specifying the fields without typing each one out?